# Capturing audio/video from RCA connectors programmatically on android device

Tags: android, video-capture

I have some problems to find infos on programmatically accessing video and audio input on 2 DIN Car Stereo Head Unit running Android 4.4. The device (KD C0223, see it [http://www.amazon.com/Capacitive-Multi-touch-Navigation-KD-C0223-Y0801/dp/B00PU7JFAO](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00PU7JFAO)) has several RCA connectors for input of audio and video . I just want to know programmatically get the stream from these RCA Inputs. On the device, an app is already installed (called « AVIN ») that get the stream from the video RCA connectors and it works fine. 
I have already try to access it using android.hardware.camera but it does not see it (my code work flawlessly with regular front camera on phone). I have looked on the TV Input Framework but I am not sure that the solution.
If someone got experience or ideas … 
Thanks